# WP7 ListBox selected item is not changing the color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a ListBox in app, it has an image and textbox inside. I want to set 2 colors and 3rd one for selected item.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="Template1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image  Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding SmallImage}"></Image>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" Foreground="{Binding txtColor}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

when I'm changing the foreground color, then the selected item doesn't highlights (I kept it by default).
I tried to add an event to ListBox,

```
private void DList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem selectedItem = DList.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;

        selectedItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    }
```

but it shows an exception:
NullReferenceException
"Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance"

Comment: Post us please how do you define the ListBox in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to handle the `SelectionChanged` event, then you might as well use the [`SelectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object:

```
private void DList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedDataObject = e.AddedItems[0]; // assuming single selection
    ListBoxItem selectedItem = 
        ListBoxName.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedDataObject);
    selectedItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: ListBoxItem selectedItem = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedDataObject);
it shows an error on this line:
An object reference is required for a non static field.
maybe there is any other way how to change the highlighting color?

Comment: I was thinking about ArrayList{public SolidColorBrush txtColor}
and when I'm trying ListBox = ArrayList, the values in xaml aren't up to date..

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code. Try naming your `ListBox` and using that name as in the example.