# ListBox isSelected method changes text style

Tags: windows-phone-8

simple noob question again.  I have a windows 8 phone app with a ListBox loaded with ListBoxItems (that are just plain text).  I set the foreground color of the text to white in xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="L1" Foreground="white">
```

Once I invoke the SelectedIndex property of ListBox, the foreground changes to red.  It does this whether I set it in xaml or c#.  If I try and add code in c# to change the color manually after SelectedIndex has been invoked, it still doesn't work...

```
tempListBoxItem = listBoxPicType.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
tempListBoxItem.Foreground = //some color that isn't red
```

what is the simplest way to get around this?  TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 ListBox selected item is not changing the color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003028/wp7-listbox-selected-item-is-not-changing-the-color)

Comment: I've removed a tag from your title - please note than in most cases [questions shouldn't include tag in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 1):

It has a simple way to achieve it, you can change the ListBoxItem ControlTemplate. This is the code for details

you can put the `style` within the resource of the PhoneApplicationPage, change the `Selected VisualState`

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <!--The selected state, change the value to your color-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Your Color"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

`ListBox`

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"/>
```

Wish this can help you. Thanks